# How to solve the UPDATE command denied to user in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to solve the UPDATE command denied to user in mysql?
yesterday it is working the update operation but today it is not working.
I am checking in the my privileges but the update is there.
What is the reason this error coming?

[image]

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: this is the error  Error Number: 1142

UPDATE command denied to user 'b2c062bb7cfeaa'@'168.62.193.30' for table 'bd_users'

UPDATE `bd_users` SET `lastlogin` = 1354507540 WHERE `uid` = '291'

Filename: C:\DWASFiles\Sites\testit\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Answer (score 5):

This can occur when your mysql DB is full.

Comment: I can't believe I've never figured that. I guess the error message could be more explicit...

Answer (score 2):

Try executing as admin

```
GRANT UPDATE ON <database name>.* TO <username>
```

as you seem to be missing the `UPDATE` in the list.

Alternatively use something like the workbench to do this.

**EDIT**

From the comment above

```
GRANT UPDATE ON <database name>.* TO 'b2c062bb7cfeaa'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
GRANT UPDATE ON `database_name`.`table_name` TO `username`@`localhost`
```