# UPDATE MySQL is not working with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem with my code and I don't know why it is not working, I hope you can help me, the code looks fine but is not updating the records, some ideas?

```
<?php
$folio = $_POST['folio'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "database") 
or die("Error en la conexion: " . mysqli_error($link));

// Printing variables to check out everything is ok

echo $folio . '<br />';
echo $nombre . '<br />';
echo $fecha . '<br />';
$consulta = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE solicitudes SET folio = '$folio',
            nombre = '$nombre',fecha = '$fecha'
            WHERE folio = '$folio'") or die("Error: " . mysql_error());

if ($consulta)
    {
    echo "it's working";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "is not working";
    }

?>
```

Comment: use mysqli_error($link)); instead of  mysql_error());

Comment: is `database` your DATABASE name.

Comment: no, it's just an example

Comment: create database firstly and run this code.

Comment: first create the database then the required tables with columns then try.do not ask before trying .

Comment: it's just an example name, the database exist and everything is working with the insert and select from the database but not with update

Comment: what error is shown when fire the query with  mysqli_error($link));

Comment: Is `$_POST` working fine? Try echoing the query `echo "UPDATE solicitudes SET folio = '$folio',
            nombre = '$nombre',fecha = '$fecha'
            WHERE folio = '$folio'"` and see if everything is fine

Comment: this is the error showed with mysqli_error($link) " UPDATE command denied to user 'max_2014'@'localhost' for table 'solicitudes'"

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677105/how-to-solve-the-update-command-denied-to-user-in-mysql

Comment: can u show you error

Comment: echo the query > copy the query and go to phpmyadmin> select database > Sql > paste the  query > go then tell

Comment: Problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

check the following:-

`$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");`
   
   `if (!$con)
   {`
   `die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());`
   `}`

`mysql_select_db("databse",$con);`
   `mysql_query("UPDATE solicitudes SET folio = '$folio',nombre ='$nombre',fecha = '$fecha'WHERE folio = '$folio'")`